# How to make "this" refer to the object when calling method indirectly?

Tags: javascript, methods, undefined, this

I want the second part of this code work to log the object, instead of undefined

```
class Ball{

    whatIsThis(){ 
        console.log(this);
    }

}

var b = new Ball();

//... test 1
b.whatIsThis(); // logs the object itself

//... test 2
var method = b.whatIsThis;
method(); // logs undefined
```

Comment: Please also see [How does the "this" keyword work?](/q/3127429/4642212) and [Losing "this" context in JavaScript when passing around members](/q/30486345/4642212). Everything is explained there.

Comment: `b.whatIsThis.bind(b)`.